# My Bootstrap Navbar Toggle is Not Toggling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

So I´ve been struggling for weeks now trying to understand what have I done wrong with the following code. Works like I want it to do, til I shrink the browser and then the menu will just stay opened no mattere how many times I click in the toggle. I would like it to be closed as a default behaviour and open just when the toggle is clicked.

I have done it thousands of times, but this time it just wouldn´t work! Any help is really much appreciated!!

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>WEBPAGE</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Main Navigation-->
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand bg-dark" href="#"><strong>NAME</strong></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="navi collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-between">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark active" href="#">OPTION1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION4</a>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION5</a>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION6</a>
                </li>
        </div>
      </nav>  
    </header>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you should also include you all css code also..

Comment: and your jquery code could be useful aswell

Comment: @MohitGupta I checked if that´s the problem and it just isn´t... works the same with the css imported or without it...

Comment: @JonasPraem haven´t written any! I´m just using the jquery and bootstrap scripts

Answer (score 0):

This simply because you're importing the `bootstrap.min.js` twice 
both cdn , and local js .

Remove the CDN js it will work correclty ( and dont forget , always put Jquery on top of all bootsrap js files )

also remove all duplicate css cdn.

Comment: You´re right I was importing it twice, thanks for that, but it wouldn´t work anyway. Now the toggle closes the navbar, but it automatically pops up again as soon as the close-transition effect ends. Any other idea? I´m so pissed off with this error...

Comment: remove all duplicate css also an retry please

Comment: it seems the problem was displaying the navbar items as a flex. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this html code only..........  don't check into code snipt.. just copy html cody and check into your file..  because file path is coming form your folders.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>WEBPAGE</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
   <!--Main Navigation-->
      <header>
        
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-dark active" href="#">OPTION1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION4</a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION5</a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">OPTION6</a>
                    </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>

      </header>
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: So it seems my only problem was displaying the items like a flex! is the only thing that i see different, isn´t it? How would you place them among the whole width with this solution but without using the bootstrap flex classes?